# Phototcurrent illuminated gold plate

Tags: optics, photons, electric-current, photoelectric-effect

Let's say we have a gold plate connected to a current meter and illuminate the plate. How would you calculate the photo current?
My first idea was to check the ionization energy of gold $E_{ion}$ and the incoming photons with a larger energy per second ($N_{ph}/s$). Then the current I should be $I = e \cdot N_{ph}/s$.
But gold is a conductor. Do you really need to ionize the gold? How would the calculations change?